# zshrc export GPG_TTY=$(tty) says not a tty

Tags: arch-linux, zsh, tty, gpg

When I put `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` in my `.zshrc` and restart terminal window and execute

```bash
echo $GPG_TTY
```

it says `not a tty`.

When I source `.zshrc` by

```bash
source ~/.zshrc && echo $GPG_TTY
```

it correctly reports `/dev/pts/1`.

**What could be that my `.zshrc` fails to find tty when its documentation says that `.zshrc` is used for interactive shell initialisation?**

Here is my `.zshrc` contents:

```bash
# Enable Powerlevel10k instant prompt. Should stay close to the top of ~/.zshrc.

if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
fi

export ZSH="/home/ashar/.oh-my-zsh"
export EDITOR=nvim
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)

ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"

plugins=(git zsh-autosuggestions)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`tty` command requires that stdin is attached to a terminal. When using [Powerlevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k), stdin is redirected from `/dev/null` when [Instant Prompt](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/#instant-prompt) is activated and until Zsh is fully initialized. This is explained in more detail in [Powerlevel10k FAQ](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/#how-do-i-enable-instant-prompt).

To solve this problem you can either move `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` to the top of `~/.zshrc` so that it executes before Instant Prompt is activated, or (better!) use `export GPG_TTY=$TTY`. The latter version will work anywhere and it's over 1000 times faster. `TTY` is a special parameter set by Zsh very early during initialization. It gives you access to the terminal even when stdin might be redirected.

Comment: Oddly using export GPG_TTY=$TTY didn't work for me, I had to move it to the top as well.  Seemed to just produce a null value.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it so, just sharing it with others.

I moved the `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` to top. Specifically above the p10k instant prompt initialization. I don't know but if I export tty after that script is executed the tty is not available. Anyways, I am not an expert in the field but it just solves the issue for me and I hope it does for you too.