# gpg: signing failed: No such file or directory

Tags: debian, gpg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been using GPG on WSL2 Debian for some time now and everything worked perfectly, but yesterday I started receiving an error about gpg signs when using git.

Trying to run `echo "test" | gpg --clearsign`, I receive the following message:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA512

test
gpg: signing failed: No such file or directory
gpg: [stdin]: clear-sign failed: No such file or directory
```

I tried the following to fix the problem:

- Kill gpg-agent with `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` and `killall gpg-agent`
- Restart WSL2
- Restart my host machine
- Generate a new key, which gives me the same message as test sign
- Create a `gpg.conf` file with `no-tty` option
- Use `chmod 700` on `~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d`

I'm using gpg version 2.2.27 with libgcrypt 1.8.8.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out that something overwrote my `tty` variable, which made gpg go crazy, because in my `.zshrc` I had exported `GPG_TTY` as `$(tty)`. I managed to solve this issue with `` export GPG_TTY=`tty` ``.

Edit: After further investigation I found out that the fault lies within Powerlevel10k, for more info see [this StackExchange thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608842/zshrc-export-gpg-tty-tty-says-not-a-tty).

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue using Rider on Debian.

Finally resolved it by following these instructions: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GnuPG#Unattended_passphrase

Add `allow-loopback-pinentry` to `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`

Add `pinentry-mode loopback` to `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`